# 文字列のコロンを削除したい。

Tags: java

下記のコードでコロン(:)のみを削除して新しく変数に入れたいと思います。どういうコードを使うのが最適でしょうか。

```
String beginTime = "9:45";
String endTime = "19:45";
```

Comment: 例えば、`"1:11"`だとしてコロンを削除したら`"111"`になって１時１１分か１１時１分か区別が付かなくなるような気がしますがそこら辺は大丈夫なのですか？

Comment: 大丈夫です。「111」は1時11分で,「1101」が11時1という形で考えてます。

Answer (score 2):

単純に`String#replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`を使えばよいかと思います。

```
beginTime.replace(":", "");
```

実行効率を少しでも上げたいのであれば文字数が4文字かどうかで分岐して`char[]`を使用するのが早いような気はしますが、実用上そのような手間を掛ける意味があるとは思いません。

Answer (score 0):

最適かどうかはわかりませんが、
[StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)を使う例：

```
public static void main(String argv[]){
    String beginTime = "9:45";
    String bt = deleteColon(beginTime);
    System.out.println(bt);
}
public static String deleteColon(String str){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.indexOf(":"));
    return sb.toString();
}
```